# Adding Tags to standard Wordpress Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm attempting to the API (and xml-rpc) to write some new articles and post them to a wordpress instance. However I am having issues with the fact that:

1. I can only add Tags for a new post that already exist.
2. I cannot find a way to add a Tag to the standard Tag taxonomy.

The plan is to add additional tags to the tag cloud and then make the post. However I am getting the following issue when I try to add a tag.

```
    xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 401: 'Sorry, you are not allowed to create terms in this taxonomy.'>
```

Here is an excerpt of the code. Is there a way to get this working. Is there anything I can do from wordpress to enable this setting

```
content = {"name": term, "taxonomy": "post_tag"}
    _ = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(wp_url).wp.newTerm(blog_id, wp_username, wp_password, content)
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but why don't you use the newer [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)?

Comment: @SallyCJ I did not know there was one. Thanks though. I'll look at it.

Comment: No problem, and you'd want to check out the [Tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/tags/) and [Posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) endpoints. But note that write/update/delete operations (e.g. creating a new post tag) require [authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/).